# Implementing 'await' type behavior to non-awaitable task

Tags: c#, wcf, events, asynchronous, delegates

There is a difference in the APIs for Windows Phone 8 and standard .NET when accessing WCF services. The API for WP8 forces the use of callbacks rather than offering awaitable interface. Furthermore, I use custom headers for the service calls that also include some shenanigans that are different on these two platforms (I would prefer my code to be runnable on both though).

Anyway, I ended up with a pattern similar to this:

```
    private bool mOperationCompleted = false;
    private OperationResultType mOperationResult;

    public async Task<OperationResultType> WCFServiceRequestOperationName()
    {
        mClient.WCFServiceRequestOperationNameCompleted += WCFServiceRequestOperationNameCompleted;

        PerformRequest(mClient, () => mStoreClient.WCFServiceRequestOperationName(dem parameters for this particular call));

        while (!mOperationCompleted ) { await Task.Delay(500); /* delay isn't mandatory here */ }

        // Reset
        mOperationCompleted = false;

        // Return
        return mOperationResult;
    }

    void Client_WCFServiceRequestOperationNameCompleted(object sender, WCFServiceRequestOperationNameCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        mOperationResult = e.Result;
        mOperationCompleted = true;
    }
```

mClient here is the ServiceReferenceClient generated by VS2012. So basically when I await for the async operation, I get 'await-like' behavior; i.e.

```
var result = await WCFServiceRequestOperationName();
```

So my problem is, how to wrap this pattern in a class so I can simply call it in a generic fashion for any WCF service call. I am fairly certain that generics and delegates might have a solution for this, but I can't pass events as parameters, so I don't know how I can add the handler in a generic fashion.

I want something like this, because I do not want to copy-paste and adjust this for every request I make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really want to use a polling pattern for your WCF calls. Instead, follow the [standard pattern for wrapping EAP members in TAP methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP). I like to make them extension methods, so they're only written once and can be used from anywhere:

```
public static Task<OperationResult> OperationTaskAsync(this WCFService client)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<OperationResult>();
  OperationCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
  handler = (_, e) =>
  {
    client.OperationCompleted -= handler;
    if (e.Error != null)
      tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
    else if (e.Cancelled)
      tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    else
      tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
  };
  client.OperationCompleted += handler;
  client.OperationAsync();
  return tcs.Task;
}
```